# Integrating $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}dy$

Tags: definite-integrals

What do I need to manipulate to show that 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^4}}dy=\frac 1  4 \int_0^1 t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt$$

Comment: you are missing some constant... Just make a substitution $t=y^4$

Comment: @leshik sorry, thanks, i missed $1/4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $t=y^4.$ What then is $dt$ in terms of $y$ and $dy$? Solve that equation for $dy$ and substitute $y=t^{1/4}$ to finish.

Why did I make that choice? Well, $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-y^4}}=(1-y^4)^{-1/2},$$ so it was a fair guess that that substitution might work, and it did.

Comment: Glad we don't have to compute that integral....

Comment: That integral's just $$\frac14B\left(\frac14\;,\;\frac12\right)\;,\;B=\text{the Beta function}$$